# Is it a problem that visa was printed next to already stamped page?

Tags: visas, uk, passport-stamps

I noticed that the page UK issuing authority selected for the printing of the visa is just next to the stamped page that I got during my UAE visit in 2016.

I am confused about this arrangement. Can it create a problem for Immigration to stamp when I arrive during my upcoming journey?

Comment: I did a bit of an edit, so that there's a question. I apologize if I've misunderstood, and you can amend as needed.

Comment: Purely FWIW, this has happened to me many times, and so far has never been a problem.

Comment: I have had full page visas glued on pages fully stamped...several times, and not by my asking.

Answer (score 16):

The [passport space requirements](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide) for a UK visa are as follows:

> You need a page in your passport that’s blank on both sides for your visa.

This doesn't mean a blank double page, but a single page which is blank on both sides. This is because applying a UK visa vignette embosses the passport page, so the back of the page needs to be clear of obstructions. Since your visa was issued, you presumably met this requirement. You will need space somewhere in the passport for your entry stamp, but there's no requirement that this is placed facing the UK visa. The border officer can put it anywhere in the passport that there is space. Don't worry about it! Enjoy your trip.

Comment: ^ This. It's even possible in some circumstances to have a visa in one passport and the entry stamp in a whole different passport. Don't worry about it.